# How to use a font, that you do not have on your computer, to a site?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I got a psd from my client using Museo Slab 900 and Museo Sans. The fonts are not in my computer. They are paid fonts. So I don't think I can use font face. Does that mean I have to make it an image? It there any alternative to solve this problem?

Comment: You can buy the web font version - https://typekit.com/fonts/museo-slab

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp read this, it'll help.

Comment: If the client has the fonts and has paid for them...can they not send you a copy **just for their work**?

Answer (score 0):

[Museo Slab Webfont](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Museo-Slab). FontSquirrel seem to have a free web font license. Make sure you keep all licensing with the typeface intact and you should be fine.

**The license says:**

"Direct Linking or Embedded Opentype Files with the @font-face CSS property (ONLY for FREE fonts)

If the font is a free font ($0.00 license fee), you may use this font for Font-Face embedding, but only if you put a link to http://www.exljbris.nl on your page and/or put this notice /* A font by Jos Buivenga (exljbris) -> http://www.exljbris.com */ in your CSS file as near as possible to the piece of code that declares the Font-Face embedding of this font."

However, read the license carefully. This might not apply to this specific font, though, I see no reason for it to not considering the font *is* free to download.

The free version only includes a **weight of 500**.

Comment: Just to note, that this is the 500 weight version only.

Comment: and it's an offsite download that restricts uses of webfont, so download the font files and use FontSquirrel's webfont creator

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest way**
Get link of the font you want from Google and add that link in head tag :
`<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ruthie" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chewy:regular|Architects+Daughter:regular"/>`
and add its name in css : 
`h1 
{font-family:'Chewy'}
div
{font-family:'Ruthie'}`
 I hope you got it.